# My variable is not being filled, remains empty

Tags: php, date, compare

I have a problem with comparing dates. I pull one date from a database through an API. These dates are stored in an array because one column contains multiple dates and I have to cycle through them to find the next upcoming date. The dates are in the format: 'dd/mm/yy'

```
$rawDate = $e->calendarsummary;
$filter = preg_replace("/[a-z]/","", $rawDate);
$createArray = explode(',', $filter);
$dates = array_filter(array_map('trim', $createArray));
foreach($dates as $d)
{
     $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmy', $d);
     if($dateTime >= $now)
     {
          $finalDate = $dateTime;
          $total = $finalDate->format('l j/m/y');
          break;
     }
}
```

If I place a var_export of $dateTime after `$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmy', $d);` it returns 'false'. So I'm guessing $dateTime is empty although my array $dates is filled correctly.

a var_export of $dates returns:

> array ( 0 => '15/06/13', 1 => '16/06/13', )

and a var export of $now returns todays date: '16/06/13'

So I'm a bit stuck why my variable $DateTime remains empty?

EDIT: Apparantly the return of 'false' means it's an error, so something went wrong when formatting my dates from the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `$dates` array contains elements such `15/06/13` so use just use wrong date format. E.g.:

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $d);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $d);
```

not

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmy', $d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dates are in format `d/m/y`, not `dmy`. Try the following instead:

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $d);
```

When I do that, I get:

```
class DateTime#1 (3) { public $date => string(19) "2013-06-15 17:17:12" public $timezone_type => int(3) public $timezone => string(3) "UTC" }
```

... instead of `bool(false)`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use **strtotime** as a different method.

```
$now = date('d/m/y');

foreach($dates as $d)
{

if(strtotime($d) >= strtotime($now))
{

       $finalDate = $dateTime;
       $total = date('l j/m/y', strtotime($d));
       break;
    }

}
```